# I want to use Python to list a directory, then sort the filenames by size

Tags: python

The following gets the files, but they are not sorted.

```
    for fn in os.listdir(path):

        if fn[0] == '.':
            continue

        try:
            p = os.path.join(path, fn)
        except:
            continue

        s = os.lstat(p)

        if stat.S_ISDIR(s.st_mode):
            l.append((fn, build_tree(p)))
        elif stat.S_ISREG(s.st_mode):
            l.append((fn, s.st_size))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import operator

for fn in os.listdir(path):

    if fn[0] == '.':
        continue

    try:
        p = os.path.join(path, fn)
    except:
        continue

    s = os.lstat(p)

    if stat.S_ISDIR(s.st_mode):
        l.append((fn, build_tree(p)))
    elif stat.S_ISREG(s.st_mode):
        l.append((fn, s.st_size))
```

For ascending sort:

```
l.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

For descending sort:

```
l.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Comment: that last line did it for me.  For a reverse sort, I made it:l.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

Comment: Glad it helped, I added both methods to the answer.

Answer (score 11):

A way

```
>>> import operator
>>> import os
>>> getall = [ [files, os.path.getsize(files)] for files in os.listdir(".") ]
>>> sorted(getall, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Answer (score 7):

Using sorted is the most efficient and standard way.

ascending:

```
sorted_list = sorted(files, key=os.path.getsize)
```

descending

```
sorted_list = sorted(files, key=os.path.getsize, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will give you some ideas:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/